# Glide downloadOnly and it's parameters

Tags: android, android-glide

I noticed Glide has the ability to pre-fetch images with downloadOnly like:

```
Glide
    .with(getApplicationContext())
    .load(myUrl)
    .downloadOnly(1000, 1000);
```

But I don't understand the parameterization. Do I need to know the exact size of the image I'm trying to fetch? Or is it an upper parameter? What if I don't know that? Why is it needed in the first place, when I'd like to Glide just get whatever is on the other end and transform it to a size only when I want it?